# TeX-complete-symbol doesn't work in math mode

Tags: emacs, auctex, auto-completion

I can't get AUCTeX to complete user-defined commands in math mode.

As an example, `TeX-complete-symbol` works outside of math mode in the document below, but it stops working if I prepend a dollar sign to the command name, returning `TeX-complete-symbol: Can’t find completion for "\rnd"`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\rndvar}{X}

\begin{document}

\rnd%      TeX-complete-symbol works here
$\rnd$%    but not here,
$\rnd%     nor here.

\end{document}
```

I'm on GNU Emacs 25.2.2, AUCTeX is v. 12.1.2. My `init.el` consists of

```
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(require 'reftex)
```

Comment: Did you try `$\rnd`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes ma'am. The behaviour is the same as when it's wrapped in dollar signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open your example file above and do <kbd>C-h v TeX-complete-list RET</kbd>, you see in the value a list item like this:

```el
(LaTeX--after-math-macro-prefix-p 1
                                  (lambda nil
                                    (append
                                     (mapcar #'cadr LaTeX-math-list)
                                     (mapcar #'cadr LaTeX-math-default)))
                                  (if TeX-insert-braces "{}"))
```

This means that in math expressions, the completion function looks in the variables `LaTeX-math-list` and `LaTeX-math-default` for completion candidates.  `LaTeX-math-list` is the one for users to customize.  As a test, you can add a comment like this to your document:

```
% (setq LaTeX-math-list '((nil "rndvar" nil nil)))
```

put the cursor after the last parenthesis and hit <kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>.  Now try `TeX-complete-symbol` again.  For me, it works and looks like this:

> [image]

Now you have make this addition permanent.  You can use the `custom` interface, make an addition on a file-local basis:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% eval: (add-to-list 'LaTeX-math-list '(nil "rndvar" nil nil))
%%% End:
```

or even write your own AUCTeX style (would be my choice).

While running the completion, Emacs will probably throw a message like this in the Minibuffer:

`TeX-complete-symbol: Wrong type argument: stringp, (if TeX-insert-braces "{}")`

This seems to be a bug.  Please report it to `bug-auctex@gnu.org`.

Comment: Do you know a way of adding every command I define to the `LaTeX-math-list` automatically?